# Getting TypeError: expected string or buffer in python

Tags: python

I have this simple code:

```
#usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tldextract

def scrape(url):
    main_domain = tldextract.extract(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    list = []
    for href in soup.find_all('a'):
    link_domain = tldextract.extract(href.get('href'))
    print link_domain
    print
```

Getting Error As :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cloud.py", line 20, in <module>
scrape("--- url here -- ")
File "cloud.py", line 14, in scrape
link_domain = tldextract.extract(href.get('href'))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 196, in extract 
return TLD_EXTRACTOR(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 127, in __call__
netloc = SCHEME_RE.sub("", url) \

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

How can i fix it.

Comment: Paste the full traceback?

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 196, in extract
    return TLD_EXTRACTOR(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 127, in __call__
    netloc = SCHEME_RE.sub("", url) \
 
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your `a` tags do *not* have a `href` attribute, so `.get('href')` returns `None`.

Use:

```
link_domain = tldextract.extract(href.get('href', ''))
```

to return an empty string in that case, or test for the attribute first:

```
href = href.get('href')
if not href:
    continue

link_domain = tldextract.extract(href)
```